# How to scope permission per application in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We would like to use Microsoft Graph API to integrate Azure AD with our SAAS Application so that it is possible to manage the Application users and groups from Azure AD and vice versa

We tried using Microsoft Graph API but Reading and Writing groups/users require Azure AD Admin permission.

Our client does not want to give us  Azure AD Admin permission as it gives our application access to all their users and groups and not just the ones that use our Application.

Turns out Azure does not allow you to scope permission per application.

I found this [article](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37796059-restrict-permissions-to-app-only-azure-ad-applicat)   looks like Microsoft is already working on adding Application scope restriction for Office 365 services. Not sure if this will be also applicable to Azure AD as well.

Turns out it's actually possible to restrict permission for apps that use [Exchange Online mailboxes](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/scoping-microsoft-graph-application-permissions-to-specific-exchange-online-mailboxes/)

I do not want to believe there is no way of scoping the permissions in Azure AD already or maybe there is a workaround for this.

Comment: This is the only thing I've ever found related to this question.  This is insanely difficult to grok if you don't know exactly what to ask for and how to phrase it.

Comment: Sorry, what is?

Comment: Your post is the only thing I ever found about this issue.  This is such a practical use case for azure and such an obvious thing to want.  I'm just surprised that there isn't more of a demand for scoping to applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that it is not supported today. I would encourage you to ensure that your specific scenario is commented in the UserVoice feature request. For instance, would you ask the customer to consent permissions to X number of named AD Groups that you can manage membership of? Or that AD Groups that your application creates, you can manage and control membership of?

Comment: I think both are valid for our scenario.

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: No this has not been prioritized. The best place to keep up with this is with the UserVoice request if it existed or create one and follow it.