# How to Limit/restrict CallRecords.read.all API permission in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I Have to restrict API permissions CallRecords.read.all permissions in azure Active directory, any suggestions on how to limit this ?

Comment: Hi @harish tej, Can you please explain little bit more what you trying to do ?

Comment: hi shruthi we need to restrict application access for API Callrecords.read.all where API is not limitable by application access policy and we need to allow this access to only set of users or group not for everyone in the tenant

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On Workaround You can’t restrict the **`CallRecords.read.all`**  Application permission  Reference:
[How to scope permission per application in Azure Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399059/how-to-scope-permission-per-application-in-azure-active-directory?rq=1)

For the **MailBoxes** you can restrict the Application  permissions

Use the **`New-ApplicationAccessPolicy`** cmdlet to restrict or deny access to a specific set of mailboxes by an application that uses APIs (Outlook REST, Microsoft Graph, or Exchange Web Services (EWS)).

Configure ApplicationAccessPolicy. To configure an application access policy and limit the scope of application permission

- Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell. For details, see [Connect to
  Exchange Online PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)
- Identify the app’s client ID and a mail-enabled security group to
  restrict the app’s access to. Identify the app’s application (client)
  ID in the Azure app registration portal. Create a new mail-enabled
  security group or use an existing one and identify the email address
  for the group.
- Create an application access policy. Run the following command,
  replacing the AppId, PolicyScopeGroupId, and Description arguments.

**Example:**

```
New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AccessRight RestrictAccess -AppId "e7e4dbfc-046f-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b" -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@AppPolicyTest2.com -Description "Restrict this app's access to members of security group EvenUsers."
```

This example creates a new application access policy with the following settings:'
AccessRight: RestrictAccess, AppIDs: e7e4dbfc-046f-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b, PolicyScopeGroupId: EvenUsers@AppPolicyTest2.com, Description: Restrict this app's access to members of security group EvenUsers.

- Test the newly created application access policy. Run the following
  command, replacing the AppId and Identity arguments.

  `Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity user1@contoso.com -AppId  e7e4dbfc-046-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b`

The output of this command will indicate whether the app has access to User1’s mailbox

For more details refer this SO Thread:

1. [How to restrict/limit Azure App Registration API permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68758591/how-to-restrict-limit-azure-app-registration-api-permissions)